# How to show pushpin when double click?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I want to show pushpin when double click in map but pushpin not show. Thanks a lot.

Source code :

```
         var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),         
         { credentials: "Key", center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-00,00)zoom: 10 });
```

*//add pushpin*

```
       var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($map.get(0), mapSettings);
       Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'doubleclick', function (e) {
       var latitude = "";
       var longitude = "";
       var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude);
       var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, {'draggable': false });
       map.entities.push(pushpin);
```

*// Update destination count*

```
       $('#destinations-count').html(nodes.length);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

To bind the double click on the Map Control of Bing Maps AJAX v7, you need to use the appropriate event which is `dblclick`.

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'dblclick', yourMethod);
```

Or inline:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', function(e) { ... });
```

See the documentation on the MSDN here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx